# $each not working in mongodb

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I would like to add new data into a child element of a field in mongodb using update query with $push and $each, But it directly insert the whole part of each operator. please help me to fix it. My query given below.

```
> db.Groups.insert({ "_id" : ObjectId("55b54aa4e2aa83f1f123a1a2"), "_creator" : ObjectId("55b2932cb57f47c0be6f071f"), "_messages" : ["hi"], "_inactive" : [ ], "_active" : [ Obje

> .Groups.update({ "_id" : ObjectId("55b54aa4e2aa83f1f123a1a2")},{$push: {_active : { $each: [ ObjectId("55b2932cb57f47c0be6f072f"), ObjectId("55b2932cb57f47c0be6f073f") ]}}});
```

Result after running these queries

```
{ "__v" : 39, "_active" : [     ObjectId("55b2932cb57f47c0be6f071f"),   ObjectId("55b28b203a6b52e9b90e3cd4"),   {   "$each" : [     ObjectId("55b2932cb57f47c0be6f072f"),   ObjectId("55b2932cb57f47c0be6f073f") ] } ], "_creator" : ObjectId("55b2932cb57f47c0be6f071f"), "_id" : ObjectId("55b54aa4e2aa83f1f123a1a2"), "_inactive" : [ ], "_messages" : [ "hi" ] }
```

Expected result

```
{ "__v" : 39, "_active" : [     ObjectId("55b2932cb57f47c0be6f071f"),   ObjectId("55b28b203a6b52e9b90e3cd4"), ObjectId("55b2932cb57f47c0be6f072f"),     ObjectId("55b2932cb57f47c0be6f073f") ], "_creator" : ObjectId("55b2932cb57f47c0be6f071f"), "_id" : ObjectId("55b54aa4e2aa83f1f123a1a2"), "_inactive" : [ ], "_messages" : [ "hi" ] }
```

Comment: Which MongoDB version is this on the server? You need MongoDB 2.6 at least to support this. Also you appear to be running this from mongoose rather than from the shell as you claim. So wat is the version of mongoose you are using as well?

Comment: Oops I'm using mongo 2.0.4 version, You are correct it working in 2.6 + versions. Please post your answer below. 

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The version of MongoDB here must be a very old version, and now confirmed as 2.0.4. This should even error in 2.2.x versions due to it interpretting the `$each` as a field and rejecting it due to the reserved `$` in the field name.

Use at least MongoDB 2.4 if you intend to use [**`$each`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/each/), otherwise there is [`$pushAll`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/pushAll/), which is now considered deprecated. The only difference being between 2.4 and 2.6 is that earlier than 2.6 you **need** to combine this with the `$sort` modifer as well.